# Angular: Wait until all child components have rendered before running code

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have a directive that's at the top level of the app and queries elements via `document.querySelector` and hands them to `fromEvent`. The problem is, that when the code in the directive's `ngAfterViewInit` runs, the DOM isn't fully rendered yet so the element query returns null.

I could run the code in `setTimeout` with some arbitrary amount of time, but that doesn't seem like a sustainable, and flexible solution.

Any ideas for how this can be elegantly handled?

Right now, my code looks like some variation of this:

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
  const trackedEl = document.querySelector('#myInput');
  const input$ = fromEvent(trackedEl, 'input')
    .pipe(
      map((inputEvent: any) => inputEvent.target.value)
    )
    .subscribe((v) => {
      console.log(`Got to the observable:: ${v}`, count++);
    })
}
```

Comment: I bet there's some elegant solution (would love to read it, so I'll watch this too!), but off the top of my head, with my limited experience - I'd probably use a BehaviorSubject as number and each component would increase that number by 1 in their own ngAfterViewInit, and I'd subscribe to it from your top level. Then, if the number reached some x amount, I'd run the code.

Comment: @MishaMashina Thanks for the tip! Also, if you are watching the question, give it an upvote for more visibility. Your idea of having each component increase the number would work for a small application, but because I am working on a massive enterprise app, that would be untenable here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up finding the solution I was looking for.

The child elements were not rendered in time likely because they were responding to some outstanding http event that hadn't yet returned a response. After reading through the documentation for change detection and [ngZone](https://angular.io/guide/zone), it looked like outstanding http events count as "micro tasks."

The below code is what worked for me.

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.ngZone.onMicrotaskEmpty.pipe(take(1)).subscribe((a) => {
      this.initiateElementEventListeners();
    });
}
```

Comment: How does this know that #myInput has rendered?

Comment: This indeed works. However, Angular is planning to get rid of `ngZone` in the future. I hope they provide similar util then.

Answer (score 2):

ngAfterViewInit lifecycle hook that angular calls after it creates all the component's child views. So you have to implement it on the root AppComponent.
Then keep an observable into a service or state and just subscribe to it anywhere you wanna check.

root AppComponent:

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  title = "Angular App";
  constructor(private data: DataService){}
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.data.rendered.next(true);
  }
}
```

subscribing it anywhere:

```
export class HighlightDirective {
  constructor(private data: DataService) {
    this.data.rendered.subscribe(rendered => {
     // all components rendered here, write you code
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your best approach here would be to use something like a `ViewChild`.

So assuming your querySelector targets an `<input>` tag your html would be like (note the #myInput decorator):

```
<input #myInput ....>
```

Your .ts file would be:

```
 @ViewChild('myInput', { static: true })
  input?: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;
```

Then because we only want to resolve the event when it is subscribed to:

```
const input$ = defer(() => fromEvent(this.input, 'input').pipe(
      map((inputEvent: any) => inputEvent.target.value)
    )
    .subscribe((v) => {
      console.log(`Got to the observable:: ${v}`, count++);
    });
```

Something to this affect, but certainly `ViewChild` being key here.

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be an approach:

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
  defer(() => fromEvent(document.querySelector('#myInput'), 'input'))
    .pipe(
      subscribeOn(asyncScheduler),
      map((inputEvent: any) => inputEvent.target.value)
    )
    .subscribe((v) => {
      console.log(`Got to the observable:: ${v}`, count++);
    })
}
```

This approach is still resorting something like `setTimeout`, but in a more *elegant* way. This is achieved by using `defer` + `subscribeOn`.

By providing `asyncScheduler` to `subscribeOn`, we obtain a `setTimeout`-like functionality. The `defer` operator has been used because we want to evaluate that function which queries the DOM when source is subscribed, and recall that the subscription time is delayed by the `subscribeOn` operator.
So, by the time the source is subscribed, the DOM should be ready to be queried.

I know this is just a workaround for `setTimeout`, but I thought it would look more *fancy* with some interesting RxJS operators.

Comment: This is a very clever solution!